# Nginx duplicate default server error

Tags: nginx

I have 2 files. The default:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

server {

        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4
        listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6 << LINE 10
```

I then have a custom file:

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

http {
    server {
        server_name mydomain;
        listen 3000;
        root /projects/myproject/public;
    }
}
```

When I try to restart the service I receive this error:

```
the duplicate default server in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:10
configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I have minimal experience with nginx and was hoping somebody could point out where I might have gone wrong?

Comment: `grep -lr default /etc/nginx`?

Answer (score 10):

8 months late, but anyway...

I had the same problem - it turned out that my editor left a default~ backup file behind after I had edited default.  Nginx read both the backup and the edited version and of course found a discrepancy between the two.  Simply deleting the backup allowed Nginx to start.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I updated both GitLab and the Ubuntu server to 14.04. That apparently made nginx to get a new default config file. Just deleted it keeping the `gitlab` config made it happy again.